# Identify a movie (cartoon) about dog puppies turning evil

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking for some help in identifying an old cartoon I am sure I've seen when I was young (some 15-20 years ago).

The protagonists of this cartoon were mainly animals, dogs to be precise, and it was about the puppies turning evil because of some kind of machine, however in the end the effect was reversed and the puppies went back to normal.

I'm sorry for not giving any more clue, but I really have not any more.

Comment: Were these "normal" puppies and not anthropomorphic, talking, or otherwise cartoony?

Comment: Anthropomorphic, no, but talking, yes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be thinking of the ["Mean Machine"](http://poundpuppies1986.wikia.com/wiki/Mean_Machine), featured in the second Pound Puppies movie, *Pound Puppies and the Legend of Big Paw*, based off of the cartoon series of *Pound Puppies* in 1986.

> The Mean Machine is used to turn a person or puppy with a pure heart into an evil person or a vicious guard dog. Marvin McNasty used this machine in an attempt to rule the world. However, the effects of the Mean Machine can be reversed when one person says "I Love You" to the person who was affected by the Mean Machine. The Mean Machine can even turn the nastiest person alive into a good person when it reversed Marvin McNasty, Lumpy, and Bones' personalities.

**The Mean Machine**
[image: Picture of the Mean Machine]

**The transformed puppies**
[image: The transformed puppies]

Comment: Yes! That is it! :D

Comment: Asking your help again, I hope this doesn't bother you :) Do you happen to know how was that movie title in Italian? I've looking for it on google and imdb, but I really cannot find its title.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari:
I can't find an Italian title for the "Legend of Big Paw" movie, but it looks like the Pound Puppies cartoon was named *Gli amici cercafamiglia* according to IMDB.